# PowerShell, how to grab a window handle of a child process, Visual Studio Project example

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, process

Anybody knows how to get a handle to a window of a particular Visual Studio Project right at the start?

If I run Visual Studio Project from Powershell I immediately get handle to `VSLauncher` process which is irrelevant for me:

```
$p = Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Projects\ConsoleApplication.sln" -PassThru
Write-Output $p
Write-Output "`$p.MainWindowHandle: $($p.MainWindowHandle)"
```

Output:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName                                                  
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------                                                  
     28       6     3144       3396    48     0.02  15584 VSLauncher 

$p.MainWindowHandle: 0
```

Compare to Notepad, everything is ok with it:

```
$p = Start-Process -FilePath "notepad" -PassThru
Write-Output $p
Write-Output "`$p.MainWindowHandle: $($p.MainWindowHandle)"
```

Output:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName                                                  
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------                                                  
     91       8     1392       4772 ...28     0.02  21516 notepad                                                      

$p.MainWindowHandle: 1836724
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio `devenv.exe` is launched as a child process of `VSLauncher.exe`. You could use this knowledge to find the child and retrieve it's `MainWindowsHandle`.

```
$parent = Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Projects\ConsoleApplication.sln" -PassThru

#Wait for devenv.exe (child process) to launch.
while (($p = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_process -Filter "Name = 'devenv.exe' AND ParentProcessID = '$($parent.Id)'") -eq $null) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }

#Wait for devenv.exe to get Title (main window has handle)
while (($windowhandle = Get-Process -Id $p.ProcessId | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MainWindowHandle) -eq $null) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }

#Output MainWindowHandle
Write-Output "MainWindowHandle: $windowhandle"
```

Comment: In your example I somehow receive a handle which is different from what I receive by simply writing `$h = (Get-Process -Name devenv).MainWindowHandle`. This `$h` I can easily manipulate, while I cannot do anything with your `$windowhandle`.

Comment: That's the problem I mentioned that required adjusting the sleep value. You are receiving the MainWindowHandle for the splash screen. I've updated the answer to exclude that now.